# How to count words in T-SQL excluding HTML tags

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given a table where one column contains HTML, how can I get a word count for each row, excluding HTML tags? Basically I want to count how many words will ultimately be rendered in the browser.

Using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: The best way of doing it is definitely to use a real HTML parser, possibly using the possibility of running .NET code inside SQL server. If that's not an option and you _really_ need to hack around it, you may want to look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51950/HTML-Parser-In-SQL-SERVER-2005-Set-Based-Approach) for a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You could adapt [this SQL function to parse delimited strings](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str) to split the string be spaces, and count words that way. It will be approximate, but if you need a more accurate count it will be easier using .net, parsing the page and getting the word counts from within the html nodes.